# How to dissalow local user to login interactively?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, groups, login

I have Windows Server 2008 (non-R2) without AD.

I have a number of users. How to allow them only connect to VPN and disallow interactive login? How to setup it via creating few groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy

Local Policies > User Right Management

Modify settings `Allow log on locally` and `Allow log on through Remote Desktop`